# How to look for a good quality 11mm rotary encoder?

Tags: components, buying

The rotary encoder attached to the wheel of my dear logitech MX1000 started glitching a few weeks ago. I took it out, tried cleaning it the best I could but it was still bad.

So I went shopping online for 11mm mouse wheel encoders and got 4 random ones, each costing around 30 - 90 cents. I tried them all and they all suck even worse than the glitchy original encoder.

I need to find a better one. Usually that would mean something more expensive like the 2-5 dollar encoders I saw titled specifically to some other high end mice but unfortunately none of those would fit. All of the 11mm encoders are less than $1 and from the little batch I got, seem to have no real difference in how well they perform despite the price.

Does anyone know a good company that makes those? Or perhaps some kind of a specification detail I should look out for?

PS! Yes I know I could just buy a new and probably better mouse but I really like this one. I've replaced pretty much every button and the battery several times over its 10 years of service and I'm not about to give up on it now.

Comment: Part shopping questions are off topic here, as in most of the stack exchange network.

Answer (score 1):

If you like the mouse and want to save it, you might look for a broken one to pull parts from. Even mice from the same manufacturer with a similar wheel from the same era likely use similar encoders.

Comment: I've looked into it but its rather tricky since there were many minor versions of the MX1000, most of them with optical encoders and there is no way to tell them apart. Also they are kinda expensive at $50+ for a heavily used one or $300+ for one in new condition.